# ZSA Moonlander backtick becomes § and shift backtick is ±

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, backticks

Hello I hav the ZSA Moonlander MK2.
When I press the back-tick key, I have § as an outcome and shift back-tick produces ±.

Here is a recording of my virtual keyboard and output

How can I just have the backtick key actually do the backtick?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

nevermind I re-set the keyboard to ansi according to here and it worked, thanks!

https://www.zsa.io/moonlander/macos/